Coding application in vb.net that also uses autocad, can't get reference to the AutoCAD Application
I have been coding a windows forms application in vb.net that opens an instance of AutoCAD 2024 with the press of a button and then prompts the user to pick two points in the active drawing.
My Form
When the form loads it checks if there is an AutoCAD process already running:
Private Function GetRunningAutoCADInstance() As AcadApplication
    Try
        'Attempt to get a reference to running instance of AutoCAD
        Return DirectCast(Interaction.GetObject(,"AutoCAD.Application"), AcadApplication)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Yet the 'Get object' always returns 'Nothing'
Note that I am using the COM libraries that AutoCAD provides with each installation
I tried to find the moniker of AutoCAD in the registry. I am a complete noob so I could not find it.
I searched for the documentation of the interop. To find it you have to have AutoCAD installed, run the command VBAIDE, pick the class you want and press the question mark.
That led me to change how the object is called in 'GetObject':
Private Function GetRunningAutoCADInstance() As AcadApplication
    Try
        'Attempt to get a reference to running instance of AutoCAD
        Return DirectCast(Interaction.GetObject("AutoCAD.Application.24.3"), AcadApplication)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

fromInteraction.GetObject(,"AutoCAD.Application") to Interaction.GetObject("AutoCAD.Application.24.3")
When debugging it catches an exception of {Cannot create ActiveX component.}.
I look at the details of the exception. In the Inner exception tab if find _COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766 Integer
That leads me to believe that maybe the registry has an issue, so I reinstall AutoCAD.
When debugging the problem persists. It catches the same exception
I try running both programs as admin, maybe it an accessibility issue. Te problem persists.
How can I reference the AutoCAD application in this context?

You may consider using the Windows calculator to convert the integer into HEX (in the menu select Programmer and click DEC). Then use your favorite search engine to search for the HEX error code.

The following may be of interest: https://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/12/accessing-com-applications-from-the-running-object-table.html
